# How to access IDENTITY_ENDPOINT within Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-managed-identity

I'm currently working on an Azure Logic App where I need to access the IDENTITY_ENDPOINT to obtain tokens for various resources. I have assigned a user-assigned identity to my Logic App, but I am unsure of the best method to retrieve the IDENTITY_ENDPOINT at runtime within the Logic App's workflow.

Here is the documentation I am following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Chttp#rest-endpoint-reference

If someone could provide a working example of a logic workflow that utilizes the IDENTITY_ENDPOINT, that would be great!

Comment: It might be better to give us more context for what you’re actually trying to do.

Comment: Sure, I can provide brief context. I have a interactive OAuth 2.0 flow working for a Microsoft Entra ID Application. From this, I receive a token. Now, I am trying to do a non-interactive approach to that same app utilizing Logic Apps / Managed Identities.

Comment: are you using logic app standard ? cause the link you are following is for app service.

Comment: what are you gonna use the token for ? http request ? logic app has out of the box support for managed identity so you dont need to call the identity endpoint your self

Comment: I am using consumption based logic app and have assigned a user assigned identity.

Comment: I need the token to authenticate to a third party service. That's why.

Comment: so http request ? you can use managed identity auth direclty so it will fetch the token for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#managed-identity-authentication

Comment: Btw i dont think the IDENTITY_ENDPOINT  is exposed in logic app consumption but there are different way to get a token tho